# How to add plugins without Bukkit on a Minecraft 1.9.4 server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, mods, minecraft-bukkit

So recently I decided to make a server with a friend. I made the server successfully (I hosted it for free) but when it came to adding plugins... Well I couldn't find anything! So I don't know how to make my vanilla server into a bukkit server for free. I was wondering how to add plugins in a vanilla server, or if I could add bukkit for free, that would also work.

I am using a Mac book pro 2010 build.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add plugins if your server is vanilla
 `for example the minecraft_server_1.9.X.jar found on minecraft.net`.
You need bukkit or a more recent artifact - as bukkit was somehow closed when Microsoft bought Mojang - it's named [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/).

It's it fully compatible with bukkit plugins as it is developped using Bukkit.
I personally use Spigot 1.9 for my server and can run multiple plugins like WorldEdit, Timber, AuthMe ...

[link to Spigot 1.9.4](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/spigot-craftbukkit-bungeecord-1-9-4.146517/)

Answer (score -2):

here you could download craftbukkit free https://tcpr.ca/downloads/craftbukkit
and then you will eddit your start.bat with the name of the file somthing like this   java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.9.2.jar nogui pause
and start the start.bat file  and put  your plugins in the plugin file